# A very weird SQL query

Tags: sql

TABLE

These are columns below:

City, Name, Payout

```
Paris, Bob, 4       
Paris John, 6     
Tokio  Adam, 5    
Tokio Mike, 3
```

it should return

```
Paris, 10, bob 4
Paris 10, jogn 6
tokio 8 adam 5
tokio 8 mike 3
```

So I'm trying to get City, Name, Payout to list out City, SUM(payout), name, payout.

I know I could do it in 2 queries, but I think it will be funny to surprise my friend by doing it with one.

Edit: The answer is this:

```
SELECT 
    city, name, payout, SUM(payout) 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 
    city, name 
ORDER BY 
    SUM(payout) DESC
```

Comment: You can always JOIN the two queries into one...

Comment: ... but still you'd need two queries. And I don't even see one...

Comment: Actually, I got it!



SELECT city, name, payout, SUM(payout) FROM table GROUP BY city, name ORDER BY SUM(payout) DESC

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do with one `SELECT` (no subqueries), if the RDBMS you use supports window functions:

```
SELECT city, SUM(payout) OVER (PARTITION BY city) AS sum_per_city,
       name, payout
FROM tableX 
ORDER BY sum_per_city DESC 
       , name ASC ;
```